# If $T_n\to T$ uniformly and $x_n\to x$ weakly, then $T_nx_n\to Tx$ weakly

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, nonlinear-analysis

We say a sequence $(T_k)$ with $T_k\colon H\to H$ is uniformly convergent to $T\colon H\to H$ if $\|T_k-T\|\to 0$. I am interested in the following claim:

> For any weakly convergent sequence $(x_k)$ to $x$, the sequence
> $(T_kx_k)$ is weakly convergent to $Tx$.

This follows from weak sequential continuity of $T$ and uniform convergence of $T_k\to T$, but can these conditions be relaxed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$T_nx_n-Tx=(T_n-T)x_n+T(x_n-x)$$ Any weakly convergent sequence is bounded therefore $$\|(T_n-T)x_n\|\le \|T_n-T\|\sup_k\|x_k\|\to 0$$ Furthermore $T(x_n-x)$ tends to $0$ weakly. Summarizing $T_nx_n$ tends to $Tx$ weakly.

Comment: Thank you very much! Why does $T(x_n-x)$ tend to $0$ weakly? $T$ is not necessarily countinuous in the present case...

Comment: In hindsight this highly uses the linearity of $T$, I didn't specify it but we are dealing with nonlinear operators...

Comment: If $T_n$ are continuous then $T$ is continuous, provided they are linear. In nonlinear case how do you define $\|T_n-T\|$ ?

Comment: And what if $T_n$ are not continuous?

Comment: $\|T\|$ is defined as the operator norm of $T$, namely the supremum of $\|Tx\|/\|x\|$ for all $x\in H$.

Comment: For noncontinuous case the problem does not make sense whatsoever. even in one dimensional case. Consider $T_n=T$ where $T$ acts on $\mathbb{R}$ as $Tx=1$ when $x$ is rational and $Tx=0$ when $x$ is irrational. Then for $x_n\to \sqrt{2},$ where $x_n$ are rational $T_nx_n$ does not tend to $Tx,$ although the sequence $T_n$ is constant.

Comment: Indeed, very helpful, thank you!